# In Angular, how to get index from a FormArray object?

Tags: angular, formarray, form-control

I have a form here:

```
 form = this.fb.group({
    username: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    password: new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(10),
    ]),
    confirmPassword: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    firstname: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    lastname: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    email: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
    phone: new FormControl(null, [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern(
        '^\\s*(?:\\+?(\\d{1,3}))?[-. (]*(\\d{3})[-. )]*(\\d{3})[-. ]*(\\d{4})(?: *x(\\d+))?\\s*$'
      ),
    ]),
    roles: this.fb.array([]),
  });
```

Please notice that only the roles is a formArray object,
now I have a function that related to multipuly checkboxs, I want to store the value that what user have selected/checked:

here is the function :

```
 onChange(event: any) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(this.form);
    const roleFormArray = <FormArray>this.form.value.roles;
    if (event.target.checked) {
      roleFormArray.push(event.target.defaultValue);
    } else {
      let index = roleFormArray.value.findIndex(
        (x) => x.value == event.target.defaultValue
      );
      roleFormArray.removeAt(index);
    }
  
  }
```

On HTML, it is simple like this:

```
 <div class="form-check">
        <input
          class="form-check-input"
          type="checkbox"
          value="User"
          id="userCheck"
          (change)="onChange($event)"
        />
        <label class="form-check-label" for="userCheck"> User </label>
        <br />
        <input
          class="form-check-input"
          type="checkbox"
          value="Manager"
          id="managerCheck"
          onchange="onChange($event)"
        />
        <label class="form-check-label" for="managerCheck"> Manager </label>
</div>
```

So bacially I wish that my code runs, if user check the role - User, then it should add into array "User"  (this is successfully) , but when the User de-selected the User checkbox, ***it throw the error - Cannot read property 'findIndex' of undefined***

Don't know why the findIndex cannot provide me the index from FormArray.
Any suggestions? Thanks!!

Comment: I guess the below answer is helpful for you 
 
           let index = this.roleFormArray.findIndex(x => {
                 if(x.value == event.target.defaultValue){
                      return x;
                 }
           });

          this.roleFormArray.splice(index , 1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have added checkbox value and removed from formarray is wrong. On select, you need to create formcontrol and add it on formarray. On deselect you need to remove formcontrol from formarray.

```
onChange(event: any) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(this.form);
    const roleFormArray = <FormArray>this.form.controls['roles']; // Corrected
    if (event.target.checked) {
      roleFormArray.push(this.fb.control(event.target.defaultValue)); // Push control not value.
    } else {
      let index = roleFormArray.controls.findIndex( // Find item from controls.
        (x) => x.value == event.target.defaultValue
      );
      roleFormArray.removeAt(index);
    }
  
  }
```